# onactivityresult from non activity

Tags: android, onactivityresult

I am working on an Android library and I am having an issue.

The main application calls an initialises a library. One of the parameters is the calling activity. This activity is then used as the context when needed.

When a certain event is triggered within the main application calls a method, which then calls a new activity. At the moment, the library class uses the activity that was passed into the initalise method to create the new activity (note that the passed in activity in the initialise may not be the activity that triggered the library as it only initialised once.

The activity that is started in the library, sets a result and finishes the activity. However, the onactivity result in the library class is not called (I presume because its not an activity and the result would go back to the activity that was passed in to the initialise.

What I need to be able to do is have the library class file to get the returned result from the libraries activity.

[image: Flow]

[image: Application flow]

Comment: If the library does not return an Activity onResult, this is not going to be possible. If it does already do this, then just call startActivityForResult()

Comment: I am calling startActivityForResult but the onActivityResult is within a standard java class not an activity so the result isn't received

Comment: SO the library has an onActivityResult funciton?  If so, you need to call it from your activity's onActivityResult and pass the result along.

Comment: That's the problem. The library has to have the onactivityresult and its the library that starts the activity, the activity and the result needs to stay within the library. The result can't be returned back to the main application

Comment: This design might give you problems. If you only initialize the library once and pass it an `Activity` and hold onto it you have created a memory leak after that `Activity` is destroyed since your library will keep a reference to it.

Comment: That's a good point, I'm passing the activity so I can use it as context. Is there a way to pass the context and keep it throughout the life of the application without causing a memory leak

Comment: Call `getApplicationContext()` on the context and keep a reference to that. This still might not work in your case depending on what you are doing with the `Context`. As an example since you are starting activities I believe you can only use the application context to start an activity with the use of `FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK`.

Comment: At the very least, you can try passing `getApplicationContext()` instead of `this` . Always do this if you got choice. Besides that, why not use `ContextWrapper`?

Comment: I've added some diagrams to hopefully explain what I'm trying to achieve. Bit tricky to explain just in text I think. I've not heard of a ContextWrapper so I'll take a look

Comment: What kind of results are you trying to get back to the library? Also, the other activities and fragments must know about the library already since it is being used to start activities in some cases. Why not just have another method to pass the library the results before finishing the activity instead of trying to get `onActivityResult` working?

Comment: the library calls an activity to get some feedback from the user, and the result (which would just be a text string) be returned to the library class that called the activity(the method being called is a static method) and the library class gets the result and posts to a web service I'll be running

Answer (score 0):

Android `AccountManager` does something like this.  A request to `AccountManager` will invoke an authenticator plugin which can have an activity to get the user's username/password, etc.

`AccountManager` just uses a special `Future` called `AccountManagerFuture` to return the results asynchronously, and I would recommend you use a `Future` implementation as well to return your results asynchronously.  Then you don't need to worry about how to make the two activities connect through the library.